# Extra word spacing in the caption of a figure

Tags: spacing, formatting, captions

I cannot figure out why there is extra word spacing in the caption. Possibly because of subfigures? Thanks for any help.

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{beest} 
    \caption{ Strandbeest Janson, Theo; hacknmod.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/theo-jansen-strandbeest.jpg} 
    \label{beest}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{umbrella}
    \caption{Sample umbrella mechanism;  wiki.ece.cmu.edu/ddl/images/thumb/Umbrella-wikiFrontpage.jpg/500px-Umbrella-wikiFrontpage.jpg}
    \label{umbrella}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You need to use \raggedright.  The caption package should have that as an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the alignment of the caption material from justified to raggedright. Since you're already loading the `subcaption` package, just issue the instruction

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
```

Place this instruction in the preamble if you want it to apply to the entire document, or immediately after `\begin{figure}` if it should apply only to the two subfigures at hand.

Separately, I would like to suggest that you also load the `url` package (with the option `hyphens`) and encase the URL strings in the captions in `\url` directives. Doing so will allow LaTeX to find additional line break possibilities within the long URL strings.

A minor point: All three `\centering` instructions may be omitted, as they apply to entities that take up the full available respective widths

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' version in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
\urlstyle{same}
%%%\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    %%%\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{beest} 
    \caption{ Strandbeest Janson, Theo; \url{hacknmod.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/theo-jansen-strandbeest.jpg}} 
    \label{beest}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    %%%\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{umbrella}
    \caption{Sample umbrella mechanism;  \url{wiki.ece.cmu.edu/ddl/images/thumb/Umbrella-wikiFrontpage.jpg/500px-Umbrella-wikiFrontpage.jpg}}
    \label{umbrella}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Also thank you for the suggestion, looks much better!